# Host vs Origin header for CORS preflight request with Spring Boot & Zuul

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, cors, spring-cloud

I'm using Zuul with `Spring Cloud Camden SR5` and `Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE`

My frontend is `React.js` application served by a `Node Express` server. My API is behind zuul.

The frontend can be accessed via `https://test.mydomain.com` and the API (Zuul) via `https://api-test.mydomain.com`

In `Zuul` I do have a `CORS` filter that sets the CORS header (properly ?):

```
if(corsAllowedOrigin.contains(host)){
        log.debug("{} is allowed", origin);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    }
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", allowHeaders);
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", exposeHeaders);
chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

With React.js I use Fetch to make HTTP calls to the API.

Before each `GET` or `POST` request, the browser does an `OPTIONS` request with the following headers:

- Host: `api-test.mydomain.com`
- Origin: `https://test.mydomain.com`

When I was using `Spring Cloud Brixton.SR6` and `Spring Boot 1.3.4.RELEASE` that worked fine.

**Now however I'm getting a `403` and the error message is `Invalid CORS request`.**

Using a REST client I noticed that if I change the headers so that `Host == Origin` then I'm getting a `200 OK`

From the `CORS` [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-security) I could find:

> In addition to checking the Origin header, resource authors are strongly encouraged to also check the Host header. That is, make sure that the host name provided by that header matches the host name of the server on which the resource resides. This will provide protection against DNS rebinding attacks.

Is that the reason why I'm now getting a `403`? How can I my API running on a different host without failing the `OPTIONS` requests?

### Update

It seems I can solve the problem if I add CORS filter to each individual service behind the edge service. That is if I make sure the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is populated by each service.

Before the update I only had a CORS filter on my edge service (Zuul) and I thought it was the way to go. Surely it seems wasteful if I need to configure CORS for each service? Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it seems to work if I use the CORS filter offered by Spring (`org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.CorsFilter`):

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```